# Cannot create vue project using vue create

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

This is my installed os and package versions

- Windows 10
- Node v12.16.3
- npm 6.14.4
- @vue/cli 4.4.6

I want to create vue project using vue cli. But when I creating the project I got this error and process failed. How can I resolve this?

[image]

**There is no issue in my network. Internet works well.**

Comment: if there's no internet connectivity issue try  before creating Vue project using CLI to make sure to install Vue CLI first , here's the DOCs https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html

Comment: Yes I installed vue CLI